# add identifier to each page on site

Tags: php, html, email

So my [website](https://boonwijkkermis.com) has multiple pages where I want people to have an option to send us a message. I already have setup a php mailer but all the mails have the same layout.
How can I make to where if the message has been send form a specific page I add specific words to the mail?
The mailsender works on both the pages but the layout and everything is the same.

THIS IS THE CODE THAT WORKS FOR ME:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

$URL = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];




// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'boonwijkkermis@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "Nieuwe mail ontvangen via boonwijkkermis.com.\n\nNaam:\n $name \n\nEmail:\n $email_address \n\nTelefoon nummer:\n $phone \n\nBericht:\n$message \n\nURL:\n $URL";
$headers = "From: no-reply@boonwijkkermis.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

$URL = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];




// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'boonwijkkermis@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "Nieuwe mail ontvangen via boonwijkkermis.com.\n\nNaam:\n $name \n\nEmail:\n $email_address \n\nTelefoon nummer:\n $phone \n\nBericht:\n$message \n\nURL:\n $URL";
$headers = "From: no-reply@boonwijkkermis.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to add an hidden field in each specific page to be able to understand where the message request came from, such as:

On a page:

```
<input type='hidden' name='from' value='page1'>
```

On another page:

```
<input type='hidden' name='from' value='page2'>
```

Then in your php file check for the `$_POST['from']` value to be able to tell from which page the request came from.

So you would do something like that:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

if(!empty($_POST['from'])) { //if the from post var is not empty
    if($_POST['from'] == 'page1') { //if request came from page1
        $message .= " requested from page1"; //we append this text in the $message var
    }
}

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'boonwijkkermis@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "Nieuwe mail ontvangen via boonwijkkermis.com.\n\nNaam:\n $name \n\nEmail:\n $email_address \n\nTelefoon nummer:\n $phone \n\nBericht:\n$message";
$headers = "From: no-reply@boonwijkkermis.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;
?>
```

In alternative if you are not able to add that hidden field, you can use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` header in your php code, that would contain the full URL from where the request came from.

Comment: @DaanVandeVoorde "how do i check the $_POST['from'] value"...same way you're doing in your code currently to read the other POST values. e.g. something like this `$from = $_POST["from"];`. Then `if ($from == "page1") { //do something } else if ($from == "page2") { //do something else }`...etc.,

Comment: @DaanVandeVoorde I've edited my answer and added the full code

Comment: You need to add the input field on each page

Comment: i edited the code so if the page is not recognised $from_page = no page.
The mail keeps the same so the data does not get added.
How do i fix this

Comment: Its not fixed yet but i edited the code and it worked but then i tried it again and it broke again